# Deprecated: Directive 'allow_url_include' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, version, deprecated, shared-hosting

I upload my Laravel project on shared hosting. When I upload my project on the server it throws an exception then switched my PHP version 5.4 to 7.4. Now am facing this issue.

```
Deprecated: Directive 'allow_url_include' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
```

**I also disable the allow_url_include in my PHP ini file which exists in project root directory but it still says allow_url_include depreciated error.**

Also, I go into the PHP Multi INI Editor and change the allow_url_include but it still throw the above error.

Answer (score 8):

Remove .htaccess or change name to .htaccess.backup and WP will generate new file based on your site configuration

Comment: Didn't work for me. I belive there is a limitation in my shared hosting provider :/

Answer (score 6):

Log into your website host and navigate to your `public_html` folder and find the `php.ini` file.  Open the file and find this code:

```
; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = On
```

Change `allow_url_include = On` to `allow_url_include = Off` and save the file.

This should fix the error.

Additional detail located here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone comes across this:

Make sure that .htaccess files at **all levels** do not have conflicting code.

That is, I found that my ".../public_html/.htaccess" did not have any conflicts. However, I also had an .htaccess file in the folder level above that and it included code that read:

`# Use PHP71 as default AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php <IfModule mod_suphp.c> suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php71/lib </IfModule>`

Commenting this out resolved the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your web host uses  Cpanel, log in and under the `Software` section click `Select PHP Version`, then on the next screen click `Options`.  Under Options, unclick `allow_url_include`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see this option in my cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Please Update PHP version of your site through CPanel to 7.3. This fixed the issue for my site. Thank you!

Comment: didn't work for me. i am already on 7.4 (native) and changing didn't work

Answer (score 0):

My client had 2 `.ini` files, conflicting `max_input_var`.

Deleting `user.ini` worked for me! Payment options were greyed out in WooCommerce. Now they are showing and this "allow_url" error is gone.